# Creating array inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following response say from an API

```
[{name : Taj Mahal, lat : 111 , lng : 222},
{name : Agra Fort, lat : 333 , lng : 444},
{name : Red Fort, lat : 555 , lng : 666}]
```

I wish to populate an array like this

```
var coordinates = [[Taj Mahal, 111, 222],
    [Agra Fort, 333, 444],
    [Red Fort, 555, 666]]
```

Comment: Whats the problem

Comment: You want solution in JavaScript/PHP?

Comment: This is a fairly simple mapping. Show us what you have tried, this isn't a free code writing service

Comment: @Satpal in javascript but i thought logic would be the same in php so i tagged it as well

Comment: iterate through `Object.keys(<each_nested_object>)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map` to achieve this

```
var arr = [{ name: 'Taj Mahal', lat: 111, lng: 222 },
            { name: 'Agra Fort', lat: 333, lng: 444 },
            { name: 'Red Fort', lat: 555, lng: 666 }];


var newArr = arr.map(function (item) {
  return [item.name, item.lat, item.lng];
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: no need to initialize the new array `[]` using `.map` function

Comment: output is not separated with array i.e its `[a,b,c,d..]` instead of `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]...]`

Comment: It is array not like what you are saying.

Comment: I am sorry if its an stupid question does `[]` skips if i use `alert`

Comment: just see in console or if you want to see in alert use `JSON.stringify(newArr)`

Answer (score 2):

With upcoming ES7, you could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Taj Mahal', lat: 111, lng: 222 }, { name: 'Agra Fort', lat: 333, lng: 444 }, { name: 'Red Fort', lat: 555, lng: 666 }];

console.log(data.map(o => Object.values(o)));
```

ES5

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Taj Mahal', lat: 111, lng: 222 }, { name: 'Agra Fort', lat: 333, lng: 444 }, { name: 'Red Fort', lat: 555, lng: 666 }];

console.log(data.map(function (o) {
    return Object.keys(o).map(function (k) {
        return o[k];
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map this by using [Object.values(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var coordinates = response.map(x => Object.values(x));
```

Comment: looks familiar ;)

Comment: yeah, just edited from simple function to es7 and then saw you already gave that solution. not that complex problem tho.